# Excel: SUMIFS multiple criteria formula error

Tags: excel

I am trying to sum over a range under multiple conditions, that should ALL be fulfilled in order to give the sum as result. There are 3 columns (C,D,H) and one table. The conditions are:

- C=header of the table. (both C values and the header are characters, in "general" format, cell O2653)
- last 5 characters of D = hour (left column of the table, first cell M2656, once the formula works I would like to scroll down on the following hours)
- first 3 characters of D = last 3 characters on a second header of the table (cell N2654)

the formula is

```
=SUMIFS($H$2657:$H$2676;$C$2657:$C$2676;$O$2653;right($D$2657:$D$2676;5);$M$2656;left($D$2657:$D$2676;3);right($N$2654;3))
```

When I enter it, I receive the error: "there's a problem with this formula. Not trying to type a formula? When the first character is an equal (=) or minus (-) sign, Excel thinks it's a formula...."

This are the columns, plus column H where there are numerical values (e.g. 8):
[image]

I have tried enter combinations like ctrl+shift+enter, or to insert text within "" instead of the single cell in the criteria (maybe it was a range problem), but nothing worked.
Why is this occurring? Thank you for your help

Comment: What do you have in column D , can you paste picture of sample data ?

Comment: Done ;) you can extend them putting random 4h blocks and NEG/POS in column D

Comment: Can you try "sumproduct"  =SUMPRODUCT($H$2657:$H$2676,--($C$2657:$C$2676=$O$2653),--(RIGHT($D$2657:$D$2676,5)=$M$2656),--(LEFT($D$2657:$D$2676,3)=RIGHT($N$2654,3)))

Comment: Thank you for the help, It doesn't give error, but I get all 0

Comment: I think I got where the problem is: left and right do not consider a range as argument, it has to be a single cell.

Comment: It shouldn't give you all 0 unless one of the condition is not met , can you try evaluating the formula and see where you get false ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/181753/discussion-between-imran-malek-and-luca91).